# How do I import one set of rake tasks into another but inside a namespace?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I have three projects, I want to be able to import project B and C's rake files into project A rake file but each inside of it's own namespace:

Now to the diagram...

- ProjectA

  - rakefile.rb
    -task1
    -task2
- ProjectB

  - rakefile.rb
    -task3
    -task4
- ProjectC

  - rakefile.rb
    -task3
    -task4

From inside of ProjectB and ProjectC I want to be able to run
`rake task3 task4`
with each calling appropriate tasks

From inside of ProjectA I want to be able to run
`rake task1 task2  b:task3 b:task4 c:task2 c:task4`

This is a simplification of what I want to do. Each rake file might have dozens of tasks and the task names may or may not match from project to project.   Making sure each task runs with the correct paths is not a problem.

Additionally I would like to strip descriptions from the tasks coming from ProjectB and ProjectC so they do not display when doing a rake -T.  Although it might be nice to be able to also pull those descriptions in for say another "ProjectD"

The projects themselves are in various languages and targeting various platforms etc.  Project A contains a task that takes care of picking up the build artifacts from each project and placing them in the correct location for integration testing and deployment.

Comment: I think this is a good question. What have you done so far? Right now, it looks more like a tutorial question than a help me out question. Include what you have done, and it will be good

Comment: @HunterStevens Thanks for your feed back.  I have tried many different ways of approaching this so far (to many to list or remember) and I am continuing to research a solution on my own.  For example, currently I am researching into leveraging the Rake::NameSpace and TaskManager classes to accomplish this directly.  This probably sounds like a tutorial question because I started to think that I might just be overthinking this as it seems like the sort of thing that might be commonly desired.  So, perhaps there is something I have overlooked, in that case yes it would be a tutorial question.

Comment: Well, I upvoted you because this is a very interesting question. I am not flagging it, but just wanted to let you know

Comment: I'm curious, how were you thinking to link the projects anyway? Or is that part of your question?

Comment: @LiveNL  I should probably clarify that the projects themselves are not ruby projects; java, javascript, python, c#, objective-c  (It may seem odd but at the moment none of them are ruby projects.) The project A build script has a task that gathers the final artifacts from each project build and places them in the correct locations for the integration tests and deployment process to pick up.  The projects are independent builds, but follow a defined API.

Comment: Rails [just does cd to each subdirectory and runs rack (as $0) there](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d89ee16bbc3b78c47cce7b09de448badf42a4124/Rakefile#L28-L30), but it's quite hacky. This approach is popular with regular `make`.